# Find dash but not in certain words

Tags: regex

My request is pretty simple, I want to find all "-" but not in certain words like *start-up* or *new-york*.

I don't know if it's feasible with REGEX.

My list of excluded words is 4 or 5 words.

So my regex level stops at about `[-]`.

**EDIT:**

Long story :
I'm using the [regex block in parabola.io](https://parabola.io/transform/use-regex) which is used for finding a match using regex and replacing it with whatever floats your boat.

I have raw blocks of texts and figured out a simple way to "mimic" bullet point lists by simply adding a `<br>` before each dash found in those blocks. However, it does not work whenever there is a dash in a word like start-up or new-york.

So now I try to match all dashes except if they are found in a specific word.

Comment: Please provide minimal example what you have developed so far? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What do you mean by "find"? Do you mean return the index positions in the string of the hyphens that do not join any of the give pairs of strings?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm using the [regex block in parabola.io](https://parabola.io/transform/use-regex) which is used for finding a match using regex and replacing it with whatever floats your boat.
I have raw blocks of texts and figured out a simple way to "mimic" bullet point lists by simply adding a <br> before each dash found in those blocks. However, it does not work whenever there is a dash in a word like start-up or new-york.

So now I try to match all dashes except if they are found in a specific word.

Comment: What exactly are the words you want to exclude?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind running few steps, that might work:

- replace all dashes in each special words with a unique character sequence. The meaning is to "escape" the dashes in these words:
  `(?<=start)-(?=up)|(?<=new)-(?=york)`  to `MYUNIQUETEXT` (confirm that your text does not have `MYUNIQUETEXT` in the first place)
- then replace all `-` with `<br>`
- then replace all unique character sequences `MYUNIQUETEXT` to `-`. That is the "unescaping".

That might be faster than designing a regular expression, for the sole purpose of do it in a single pass.

Comment: That's a perfect workaround! Thank you!